# Dozer can't map Hibernate's persistentBag to List

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, dozer

I'm implementing a rest web service in Java as university assignment so I'm quite new to such things thus probably I'm doing it in the wrong way.

Anyway the problem is that Dozer can't map a Hibernate `PersistentBag` to a `java.util.List`.

I'm mapping two classes: `A` and `B`,

```
List<Department> A.departments
```

is mapped to

```
DepartmentsType B.departments
```

`DepartmentsType` has just one property which is

```
List<DepartmentType> departments
```

So in the end `A.departments` is mapped to `B.departments.departments`, infact this is the mapping:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>it.unitn.lsde.persistence.A</class-a>
    <class-b>it.unitn.lsde.generated.B</class-b>

    <field>
        <a>name</a>
        <b>name</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>city</a>
        <b>city</b>
    </field>
    <field> 
        <a>departments</a>
        <b>departments.departments</b>
        <a-hint>it.unitn.lsde.persistence.Department</a-hint>
        <b-hint>it.unitn.lsde.generated.DepartmentType</b-hint>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>code</a>
        <b>code</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

This is how I define `A.departments` (Hibernate):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "university", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
protected List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>();
```

This is how I define `B.departments`:

```
DepartmentsType departments;
```

And eventually this is how `DepartmentsType.departmens` is defined:

```
List<DepartmentType> departments;
```

Whenever a I try to map `class A` to `class B` I get a `Field Mapping Error` from Dozer:

```
Source parent class: B
Source field name: departments
Source field type: class org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag
Source field value: [it.unitn.lsde.persistence.Department@12b3c6b]
Dest parent class: A
Dest field name: departments.department
Dest field type: java.util.List
```

The exceptions stack point this code to be problemitic:

```
return (B) mapper.map((A)session.get(A.class, id), B.class);
```

However when I map `class B` to `class A` everything works as expected.
I know that, for a number of reasons, Hibernate is turning what I defined as `List` into its `PersistentBag` but this should be a `List` itself.

I'm not able to find out what i'm doing wrong, why Dozer can map `A` to `B` but not `B` to `A`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching I've found out that I was missing the setter of the List on the `DepartmentsType`'s (`B.departments`) class.

Without that setter Dozer was not able to map the list coming from Hibernate.